# What is the state of current plans for a permanent moon base?

Tags: the-moon, future-missions, lunar-base

With all the news regarding SLS/Commercial Crew and the refocus on Moon *then* Mars, I was curious as to what we will actually be able to do with these upcoming launch capabilities.

I'm familiar with [Lunar Gateway](https://www.nasa.gov/topics/moon-to-mars/lunar-outpost) and discussion of temporary landers with habitable crew spaces, but what is the state of current plans for a permanent base *on* the Moon?

Comment: This is a very broad question that can't be objectively answered.  Any assessment of a "realistic" plan is bound to be opinion based.   Perhaps narrow the scope a little?

Comment: @CarlosN I've made an edit, is this better?